# What is the differenence between ruby app.rb and rackup

Tags: ruby, rake, bundler

What is the difference between running `ruby app.rb` and `rackup`? When running `rackup`, what script is actually running?

Answer (score 1):

`App.rb` is Sinatra's front controller and can be call whatever you choose to call it

`rackup` is used to start rack based application servers it defaults to `config.ru` when no config file is supplied